# python exe in windows not writng

Tags: python

I have converted my python program to exe using pyinstaller. My exe creates a temporary folder _MEIxxxxx to keep files. In the same folder there is a file which is being changed by the program, but unfortunately it is not happening.
In the program I change the folder to go to above folder:

```
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\Public')
for foldername in os.listdir():
if foldername.startswith('_MEI'):
    myfolder = foldername
    os.chdir('C:\\Users\\Public'+myfolder+'\\Quiz')
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: don't hardcode those windows directories. They may be different. Use env.variables. The error here: missing backslash. Use os.path.join

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this doesn't work:

```
os.chdir('C:\\Users\\Public'+myfolder+'\\Quiz')
```

because `myfolder` doesn't contain a `\` at start.

Don't hardcode `C:\Users\Public`, use `PUBLIC` env. var

And avoid `chdir`, it's equivalent as a global variable shared between all modules. What if some module needs one current dir, and the other another?

Your attempt looks more like a shell script ported to python `cd xxx; ls; ...`. Break this habit.

Use absolute paths/paths passed as parameter instead. My proposal:

```
pubdir = os.getenv("PUBLIC")
for foldername in os.listdir(pubdir):
  if foldername.startswith('_MEI'):
      myfolder = foldername
      quizdir = os.path.join(pubdir,myfolder,'Quiz')
      # now do something with quizdir
```

and if you need an absolute directory to run a system call, `subprocess` functions have a `cwd` parameter for that. So you can avoid `os.chdir` 99% of the time.